# Fill dynamic Column Data in Rows.Add in Datagrid, Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagrid, rows

I'm trying to fill a Datagrid with the data fetched from a CSV file.

But I wish to add Columns dynamically, as the number of columns vary in my CSV files.

**I don't wish to predefined the Column count in my 'Rows.Add'** as below-

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(totalData[0], totalData[1], totalData[2], totalData[3]);
```

I have tried two other approaches, but in those don't do the trick.
Below is my code-

```
using (var selectFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (selectFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string filePath = selectFileDialog.FileName.ToString();
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                    string[] totalData = new string[File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length];

                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    //Fill DataGrid Column Names
                    totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                    for(int i=0; i< totalData.Length; i++)
                    { dataTable.Columns.Add(totalData[i]); }

                    //Fill DataGrid DATA
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(';');

                        //METHOD 1: Need a Replacement for this. Dont want a predefined it.
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(totalData[0], totalData[1], totalData[2], totalData[3]);

                        //METHOD 2: Doesn't Work. Fills the entire data in the very first column
                        for (int i = 0; i < totalData.Length; i++)
                        { dataTable.Rows.Add(totalData[i]); }

                        //METHOD 3: Doesn't Work. Throws a Null Pointer Exception.
                        dgDataFromCSV.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "test";
                    }
                    dgDataFromCSV.DataSource = dataTable;
                }
            }
```

Open for any idea, or nay other method/approach to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dataTable.NewRow() to create a new empty DataRow, then use a loop to assign the values to the DataRow and finally attach the DataRow to the table with dataTable.Rows.Add(newDataRow).